# Armature Shape Keys Value Additive?

Tags: rigging, armature

I have rigged my character using Rigify and everything seems solid, but when I start to make my shape keys things start to be wonky.

1. I set my armature pose: [image: base pose of Blender armature]
2. I go to my object modifier and save as a shape key: [image: Blender shape key saved]
3. Value of the shape key is 0.  If I try to use the shape key, it adds the value on, and I can't reset the pose to default, so I end up having to manually undo all of the posing in order to get it the proper weight.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Shape kesy are addictive, and they should be used, in a rigged face, to perform little corrections or deformations that can't be achieved with bones only: your  pose can be saved in a bone Pose Library and recalled as it is using standard bone animation.